# How to configure new Maven project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, intellij-idea, development-environment

I have a repetitive problem in IntelliJ IDEA. It irritates me so much, so I need to find a repeatable solution.

The issue is when I create a project in IntelliJ IDEA and want to convert it to Maven, adding folder structure manually and pom.xml file, IntelliJ IDEA can build a project with Maven but doesn't represent visually it the same way as actual Maven project:

- It doesn't auto-suggest to create a file in the language I am working in
- It represents files in folders, not packages
- Navigation is semi-broken
- Imports don't work correctly

This happens not only when I create non-Maven and convert it to Maven but sometimes when I create a Java Maven project and transform it to Kotlin Maven.

Is there any repeatable way to force IntelliJ IDEA to recognize my project as Maven and represent it visually in the correct manner?

**NOTE:** This question doesn't relate to the IntelliJ IDEA version. I have had the same problem every for the last few years. It irritates me so much because I constantly create new projects for demo/presentations, actual development.

**NOTE 2:** It isn't environment-specific, I experienced the same in both Mac and Linux

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start

Comment: @PetrRastegaev I have been there, tried that. This question wouldn't exist if what they have in the docs would work correctly.

Comment: Use **Add Framework Support** acton from the module context menu and select Maven in the dialog - IDE will automatically create pom.xml file and default Maven directory layout. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer assumes that official documentation doesn't work and you have a valid Maven project.

You will need to do one of these 2 actions. Mark your folder as Source/Test Source Root, the same applies to the Source/Test Source `resources` folder.

[image: Folder structure when Root directory isn't recognized]

[image: Mark directory as correct Root]

[image: Folder structure when Root config applied correctly]

Another solution, modify the `*.iml` file (not recommended):

[image: Source folder XML]

Both solutions will work independently of OS and IntelliJ IDEA versions.

Comment: Have you tried these instructions?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html

Comment: @Elena Yes, I tried. Unfortunately, it has never worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If so pom.xml File, directly use the reimport function of Maven.

Comment: It didn't help.